# UIView drag and drop - drag view disappears when addsubview: is called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have `DragView` objects and `DropView` objects, which are both `UIView` subclasses, inside of a `UIView` container. The following `selector` method is being called on gesture pan. The problem is that when I drag a `DragView` object onto the `DropView` object, the `DragView` object disappears. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

```
 - (void)dragViewMoved:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture{

    CGPoint touchLocation = [gesture locationInView:self];

    static DragView *currentDragView;
    static DropView *currentDropView;

   if(UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan == gesture.state){

        for(DragView *dragView in self.dragViews){

            if(CGRectContainsPoint(dragView.frame, touchLocation)){
                currentDragView = dragView;
                break;
            }
        }

    }else if(UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged == gesture.state){

        currentDragView.center = touchLocation;

        for(DropView *dropView in self.dropViews){

            if(CGRectIntersectsRect(currentDragView.frame, dropView.frame))
                currentDropView = dropView;

        }

    }else if (UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded == gesture.state){

        if(CGRectIntersectsRect(currentDragView.frame, currentDropView.frame)){

            //I think the problem is happening here
            currentDragView.center = touchLocation;
            [currentDragView removeFromSuperview];
            [currentDropView addSubview:currentDragView];

        }

        currentDragView = nil;

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Why your `currentDragView` and `currentDropView` are `static`?

Comment: Who else holds (strong reference) the `currentDragView`?

Comment: @gran33 They are `static` so that they persist between the gesture `selector` calls as the user drags the `DragView`. The parent view that is initialized in the `.xib` file holds `strong` reference to the `currentDragView`.

Comment: I added a gif to illustrate the problem.

Comment: i think you just bring them to front

Comment: @DanialHussain They are in the front already.

Comment: ok next thing you need to do is remove this line currentDragView = nil; and see the magic

Comment: @DanialHussain Same problem, no magic.

Comment: have you use the color blended layer to see whether views add to your main view

Comment: @DanialHussain The views are being added to the `subviews` array of the `currentDropView`, they just aren't appearing.

Comment: have you added your currentDropView to self.view

Comment: just need to check this out. http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/dragging-views-with-gestures

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this:

```
currentDragView.center = touchLocation;
```

Try to change to this:

```
currentDragView.center = [gesture translationInView:currentDropView];
```

Update:

Try to switch this lines:

```
static DragView *currentDragView;
```

To this:

```
DragView *currentDragView  = gesture.view;
```

Comment: Tried that, it didn't work. When I call `addSubview:` on `currentDropView` the `currentDragView` is added to the `subviews` property of `currentDropView`, it just is not appearing...

Comment: No, `currentDragView` is a `subview` of the container in which `currentDragView` and `currentDropView` are siblings.

Comment: Have u tried to remove this: `[currentDragView removeFromSuperview];`

Comment: Yes, I did remove it, as I read that a `UIView`` can only have one superview. The problem is still there after the removal also.

Comment: I think the problem had to do with the references in the `.xib` file. I removed the `.xib` file and instantiated the `UIView`s in the `-loadView` method of my root `UIViewController`. The method I found to adjust the coordinates was `-convertRect:toView:`. I honestly still don't really understand why the use of the `.xib` caused this issue.